# Get files from directory (including all subdirectories) and open file

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a small application in VB.NET that when clicking a button of DatagridView should search and open an excel file within a directory with several subdirectories ordered by years (2019 .... 2018 ......). Within these subdirectories are several Excel files named by numbers (`5673455.xlsx` ..... `11122232.xlsx` ...). The name of this file should be placed in a textbox and when clicking the button should open the file.

How can I make it so that it is not necessary to put the full name of the file in the textbox and open it? For example the full file name is "23456_B_D.xlsx" and placing the textbox only "23456" opens the file. What if the file has the extension xls and not xlsx?

Here is the code I have so far. But I'm getting an error:

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' can not be converted to 'String'

My code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView_descricao_ColumnAdded(sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                       Handles DataGridView_descricao.CellContentClick
    Dim senderGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn AndAlso
       e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\SALES", "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim fileName As String = TextBox_sa.Text + ".xlsx"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(filePaths, fileName))
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You defined filePaths as String(), but Path.Combine needs a String. You will have to loop through your array.

Comment: how? muffi? can you explain please?

Comment: Use `For Each` for this purpose. In your loop you can do what you want. But think: your Windows may not like to start hundreds of processes!

Comment: Can you show a solution to get this to work well, please? Or someone?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a coding service (e. g. for homework). But if you show us your try with your code, we can help to solve your problem(s). For the moment, take a look at the Microsoft documentation, there are very easy examples to understand, how a `For Each` loop works and how to build it.

Comment: This is not homework ,I am doing to accomplish and facilitate a task in my day to day work

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
    Private Sub DataGridView_descricao_ColumnAdded(sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                       Handles DataGridView_descricao.CellContentClick
    Dim senderGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn AndAlso
       e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\SALES", "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim fileName As String = TextBox_sa.Text + ".xlsx"

        For Each path As String In filePaths
                Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo With {
                    .FileName = path,
                    .UseShellExecute = True,
                    .Verb = "open"
                })
            Next
    End If

End Sub
```

But this opens several files !!!